# Using error names rather than error codes in pydocstyle's ignore file

Tags: python

My team's repo using *pydocstyle* to manage doc string standardization. I've been tasked with reformatting the relevant configuration file. Currently it looks something like this:

```
[pydocstyle]
ignore = D100,D203,D405
match = *.py
```

but we want something more like:

```
[pydocstyle]
ignore = "error-name1", "error-name2", "error-name3"
match = *.py
```

so that it's more obvious to readers what rules are being ignored. However from what I can see this is not mentioned in the documentation ([here](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/6.1.1/usage.html)).

Instead I thought I'd do something like this:

```
[pydocstyle]
ignore = 
   D100,       # corresponds to "error-name1"
   D203,       # corresponds to "error-name2"
   D405        # corresponds to "error-name3"
match = *.py
```

But I don't know if this is valid syntax in this file, or how to check.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to the original task I was given (`ignore="error-name1"` etc)?
2. If not, would my pseudo-solution work?

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: looks like `pydocstyle` config file is based on INI format. [Comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Comments) should be supported.

Comment: @rzlvmp Thanks its helpful to know what standard to look into. I was actually concerned about the whitespace between the values as well but it seems it's accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-solution is fine. You can test it by just running

```
pydocstyle --config=name_of_config_file
```

in console. Note `name_of_config_file` must conform to one of the standards listed [here](http://www.pydocstyle.org/en/6.1.1/usage.html#configuration-files).